# Classname First child of First Child src

Tags: jquery

I have the following elements:

```
<div class="house-box"><img class="Dicon" src="101"/></div>

<div class="house-box"><img class="Dicon" src="102"/></div>

<div class="house-box"><img class="Dicon" src="103"/></div>
```

I want to retrieve an element with class `Dicon` who's the child of `house-box`, but I only want the first `house-box`.

Here's what I have so far:

```
function SelectCheck()
{
        var select_val = $('#companyCheck').val();
        var firstChildContent = $('.house-box');
        alert(firstChildContent.find('.Dicon:first').attr('src'));
        return;
}
```

I want the `src` attribute of the first `house-box`'s `Dicon` element...

Comment: Copied example code from jsfiddle to post and better explained the problem (hopefully)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use

```
 var firstChildSrc = $('.house-box:first-child').find('.Dicon').attr('src');
```

or

```
var firstChildSrc = $('.house-box:first').find('.Dicon').attr('src');
```

or

```
 var firstChildSrc = $('.house-box').first().find('.Dicon').attr('src');
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/3b0g9s2L/6/)

Answer (score 0):

try this:get the first children the get it attribute class:your current code gives the `src` of first one which is 101.

```js
function SelectCheck()
{
        var select_val = $('#companyCheck').val();
        var firstChildContent = $('.house-box');
        alert($(firstChildContent.children()[0]).attr("class"));//Dicon
       alert($(firstChildContent.children()[0]).attr("src"));//101
        return;
}

$(document).ready(function(){
 SelectCheck();
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="house-box"><img class="Dicon" src="101"/></div>
<!-- need to get the src of this one -->

<div class="house-box"><img class="Dicon" src="102"/></div>
<!-- not this one -->

<div class="house-box"><img class="Dicon" src="103"/></div>
```